# contact form php validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

Once again I am asking help from you savvy developers out there.
This is the contact form I developed for my website:

```
<div id="contactForm">
  <h2>Escr&iacute;banos</h2>
  <div class="sepContainer"></div>
  <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <div class="name">
      <label for="name">Su nombre:</label>
      <p> Por favor ingrese su nombre</p>
      <input id=name name=name type=text required />
    </div>
    <div class="empresa">
      <label for="empresa">Su empresa:</label>
      <p> Por favor ingrese el nombre de la empresa a la cual pertenece  (opcional):</p>
      <input id=empresa name=empresa type=email required />
    </div>
    <div class="telefono">
      <label for="telefono">Su tel&eacute;fono:</label>
      <p> Por favor ingrese su n&uacute;mero de tel&eacute;fono (opcional):</p>
      <input id=telefono name=telefono />
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <label for="email">Su E-Mail:</label>
      <p> Por favor ingrese su E-Mail</p>
      <input id=email name=email type=email required />
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <label for="message">Su mensaje:</label>
      <p> Por favor ingrese su consulta</p>
      <textarea id=message name=message rows=6 cols=10 required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
      <input name="submitted" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I would like to validate this form so I can make sure I can get back to people trying to contact me.

Does anybody know a good piece of code to validate this form?
I would like to make sure that there is input in the following fields: name (only text, no special characters), telefono (optional field; if filled: only phone number, "-" allowed), email (valid email address), message (plain text, no code allowed).

If anyone could help me out on this one I would be very grateful!
Thanks a lot !

Comment: There are many answers to be found on Google, [**Click here**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mail+validation+php+form&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr) and you will see there are many options available.

Comment: (addendum) I think that `type=email` is in fact valid HTML5 markup. For all those wondering, consult http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html Call me "Old School" lol Old School "still works".

Comment: I looked up on google, and tried a couple of codes but none seemed to work Fred! It is HTML5

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Since I am an "Old School" kind of guy, rather like the old ways that still work. One should feel comfortable with what one is used to, and if it works for you and it serves you well, then "More Power to You" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Fred. However, thought I'd help out. There's a few issues with sending the form to a different page.

If your form is validated with Javascript before it submits to process.php then it's fine as you can provide a simple completion message. But if you want to validate it on process.php then the users will have to go back to the page with the form on it and losing some data put into the form.

A better approach would be to (if you want to validate via php) is to leave the action field blank `<form action=""`

Then use the following snippet to validate the form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $required_fields = array('name', 'email', 'telefono');
    $error = '';
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        $$k = $v;
        if(in_array($k, $required_fields)){
            $error .= "$k is required<br />";
        }
    }

    if(!$error){
        //do whatever you want with the results here
    }
    else{
        echo $error; //print error
    }
}
?>
```

Also, you might want to add `<?= $name; ?>` or `<?php echo $name; ?>` for the value of the name field and each other field. if you have reporting all errors on for php then initialise the variables first at the top of the page thus:

```
$name = ''; $email = ''; //and so on
```

Comment: Giving you a +1 for two reasons, **1)** Thanks for the mention, and **2)** Well explained and a good example. I will however say that you may have to pre-define your variables as such `$email=$_POST['email'];` etc., unless you've already taken care of it in `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){`? I'm pretty good with forms, but I will admit that there are some things/methods I am not aware of; then again who is? (wink) Cheers :)

Comment: @Fred thanks :) Yes $$k = $v automatically makes each field name into a variable so `<input name="email" />` will create a variable `$email` and `<input name="address" />` will create a variable `$address` with the value of the input field. I didn't explain the code as I thought he'd appreciate a solution and here's hoping it helps others as much as StackOverflow has helped me

Comment: You're welcome. Ok well I will surely study your code as I'm sure it will be beneficial for all, including myself. If there was a way to give you another +1, I would, cheers! Well done :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this one https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine and its pretty awesome if you dont mind using jQuery.

It won't submit the form until the fields are validated. It validates most kinds of field types including emails. You can also validate fields via ajax with this plugin for things like checking if usernames already exist and what not without submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zend Validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html) to accomplish all of this.

They have a simple abstract validator class with a method which checks if an input passes the validator. You can use their pre-made validators or define your own by extending the abstract.

Do NOT use jQuery validation alone as suggested by Pjack. A savvy user could disable JavaScript and submit data which does not pass your validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, but there are libraries that will do way better.

Ie with Jquery, etc...

```
<?php

 session_start();
 session_unset();


 if(isset($_POST['name'])&&(!empty($_POST['name']))){
  //do stuff with name

} else {
$_SESSION['errors']['name'] = "Please enter a name";
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

//do stuff with email

} else {
$_SESSION['errors']['email'] = "Please enter an email";
}

//repeat for all other fields


Then....

if(!empty($_SESSION['errors'])){
header("location: form.php"); //back to form
} else {
header("location: success.php");
}
```

Then in your HTML, save as a php file, and add the errors....
In a  span....

```
<div id="contactForm">
 <h2>Escr&iacute;banos</h2>
 <div class="sepContainer"></div>
 <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
  <div class="name">
  <label for="name">Su nombre:</label>
  <p> Por favor ingrese su nombre</p>

  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['name'])){echo "<span class='error'>".$_SESSION['errors']['name']."</span>";}?>

  <input id=name name=name type=text required />
</div>
<div class="empresa">
  <label for="empresa">Su empresa:</label>
  <p> Por favor ingrese el nombre de la empresa a la cual pertenece  (opcional):</p>

  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['email'])){echo "<span class='error'>".$_SESSION['errors']['email']."</span>";}?>

  <input id=empresa name=empresa type=email required />
</div>
```

This way you have access to all the errors in the `$_SESSION['errors']` array.

But the code above will merely check if the user entered stuff into the box.

Its not gonna do anything fancy, like making sure th eemail is actually an email or anything.  Like I said.....there are libraries that handle this stuff much better.  And with much more precision.

But the basics of how it works are above.

Comment: Ok, something I don't understand about your answer. First you set your session, then you unset it. Can you explain?

Comment: I dont set it...I start it.....then unset, just to make sure its empty again, before filling it. (if errors),  I wanna unset it first each time, so that its empty if there are no errors

Comment: I quote from the [**PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) *"If $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable"*. Isn't `session_unset();` used if/when logging out of something or to clear a session itself? I mean, will it still record the session after unsetting it?

Answer (score 0):

Another flexible jQuery plugin for browser-side validation is the "Validation Plugin" found at http://bassistance.de/

I would encourage you to always crate a validation method for the server side as since you can not rely on browser side validation. Users can always control the JavaScript running in there browsers.

I always start whit writing the server side validation and write the browser side just so users can get some feed back earlier in the process.

I often do somthing like Onimusha wrote for simple required controll:

```
<?php


//Globals!!
$required_fields = array('f1', 'f2', 'f3'); // to 'fn'
///// "OR":

//$field_tests = array('field_name' => 'validation_test');
$field_tests = array('field1' => 'required', 'field2' => 'tel', 'field3' => 'email', 'field4' => 'radio');

//For use when there are errors 
$restore_array = array();

//Depending on how you want to inform your users, this can be much more sofisticated..
//this method does not give you any way to indicate whitch field that did not validate correctly
//$error_message = '';

$error_array = array();
$error_dictonary = array('field1' => 'explanation', 'field2' => 'other explanaiton');


function basic_server_side_validation(){
    global $error_array, $restore_array, $error_dictonary;



    //REMEMBER TO DO APPROPRIATE trim () AND addslashes() WHERE APPLICABLE!!
    //-- note: 
    //if you have checkboxes then implemented like <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" />
    // Then this shoud be done recursively
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        $_POST[trim(addslashes($k))] = trim(addslashes($v));
    }

    //You could do this only on errors... (you could alsow combine this whith the previous loop)
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        $restore_array[$k] = $v;
    }

    //if you just have required fields 
    //-- note: 
    //if you have checkboxes then implemented like <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" />
    // Then this test need to check if that field is an array and so on (not shown here)
    foreach($required_fields as $f){
        //if you use empty, note that empty("0") is true! (in some (most) cases thats what we want..)
        if(!isset($_POST[$f]) || $_POST[$f] == '') // if(!isset($_POST[$f]) || emtpy($_POST[$f])) 
            $error_array[] = $f;
    }

    // "OR" :

    foreach($field_tests as $field => $test){
        if(!isset($_POST[$f])){
            $error_array[] = $f;
            continue;
        }

        if(! call_user_func('validate_'.$test, $_POST[$f]) ){ // or if(! 'validate_'.$test($_POST[$f]))
            $error_array[] = $f;
        }

    }


    if(!empty($error_array)){
        //Do somthing and show the form to the user agin
        //The easiest way to do this is to hawe this code in a function and return at this time!

        //NOT GLOBAL 
        //if $error_array and $restore_array and $error_dictonary IS NOT global
        //return array('errors' => $error_array, 'restore' => $restore_array, 'mesages' => $error_dictonary);

        //Whth globals:
        return false;
    }

    ///Insert into DB?? (Here or in a nother function or in calling function when returning true)
    return true;


}
//Define validation rules functions:
function validate_required($field){
    if(isset($field))
        return true;
    //default return false
    return false;
}

function validate_telephone($field){
    //some code
}



if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){
    if(!basic_server_side_validation()){
        show_form(); 
        //if show_form returns then we opt out here..
        return;
    }
    $db_status = do_db_stuff();

    if($db_status === false){
        //some error handler
    }
    //and so on

}else{
    show_form();
}

?>
```

In your html form you can then do somthing like (replace action="#" to an appropriate location or ""):

```
function show_from(){

    echo '<form action="#" method="post">';

    if(isset($error_array['field_name']))
        echo '<p>', $error_dictonary['field_name'], '</p>';

    echo '
        <label>Some text: 
            <input type="text" name="field_name" value="',(isset($restore_array['field_name']) ? $restore_array['field_name'] : '' ),'" />
        </label>';


    echo '</form>';


}
```

Note that there is many ways to do form validation, and if you require lots of tests then creating a "definition" could be a good way to go. 
Example from article "FORM PARSER USING THE SPL ARRAY ITERATOR" in phparch.com September 2009 (http://www.phparch.com/magazine/2009-2/september/):

```
$definition = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'validate' => 1,
        'validation_type' => 'alphanumeric',
        'reg_exp' => '',
        'error_message' => 'Only use alphanumeric characters',
        'sanitize' => 1,
        'sanitize_type' => 'safe',
    ),
    'last_name' => array(
        'validate' => 1,
        'validation_type' => 'alphanumeric',
        'reg_exp' => '',
        'error_message' => 'Only use alphanumeric characters',
        'sanitize' => 1,
        'sanitize_type' => 'safe',
    ),
);
```

Comment: **Wow!** That is some complex coding you've got happening here. I'm just hoping and by judging by the OP's experience, will be able to make **"heads or tails"** out of this. Let's wish the OP "Good Luck" (wink)

Comment: And just for the record, **requiered** is spelled **"required"** and **feields** is **"fields"**. One must keep good "Grammar" ALIVE. (wink)

Comment: Thanks Fred! I'm sorry for the spelling errors. I did not use a spell checker and am embarrassed now :-) I am norwegian and i don't write so much english in my daily work. My coworkers have pointed out that i tend to misspell "field" often, I will try to get it right the next time and im going to update the post :-P

Comment: You're welcome Espen. I used to be an editor for many years in the printing and books industry, so that gets the best of me every time. *Peace to you*.